# ASP.NET MVC route handling for misspelled URLs?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

How can we create a route that will detect that the URL matches a route but that the parameter to that route is wrong?

I've had several cases recently where a user has mistyped a URL and it has been hard to debug because the route table doesn't handle these misspellings very gracefully:

This route handles the URL /Widgets/guid

```
routes.MapRestfulRoute(
    "WidgetsItem",
    "Widgets/{idString}",
    new { controller = "Widgets", action = "Item" },
    new { idString = 
    @"^[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}$"}
);

routes.MapRoute("WidgetsList", "Widgets", new { controller = "Widgets", action = "List" });
routes.MapRestfulRoute("CatchAll","{*url}", new {controller = "Error", action = "Http404"});
```

And the user entered the URL /Widgets/25246810-4b60-4db8-8567-8db8826 which looks correct but is not (there's only 28 characters in that guid provided).

Because the URL didn't match the route, the response was 404.  But this is deceptive and caused a debugging problem: it looks like the Widgets/Item action is returning 404. And we spent hours trying to figure out what was wrong with that action, when in fact the action wasn't even called.  It wasn't until I installed RouteDebugger that I noticed the guid was malformed.

How can we create another error route that will detect that the URL does actually match a route but that the parameter to that route is wrong?

EDIT:  I can "fix" it by adding a new route that matches /Widgets/anything, and placing that route after the normal route:

```
routes.MapRestfulRoute(
    "WidgetsItemError",
    "Widgets/{idString}",
    new { controller = "Widgets", action = "Item" },
    new { idString = @"^.+$" } // match if it has any param at all
);
```

But this seems to be very inefficient - I will have to add a similar error route for every single route eg /Foo, /Bar /FooBar etc (and I've got quite a lot of routes).  Isn't there a more generic way to do this?

Comment: Just a note, route constraints can hurt your applications performance.

Comment: Do you have any links to discussions to support this?  How would you create a route that has no constraints and then still be able to distinguish between /Widgets/guid (returns one item) and /Widgets (returns the list)

Comment: Why are you having users manually enter a GUID? That's highly error prone.

Comment: @Rick.Anderson-at-Microsoft.com its a REST API, and they have to supply the ID of the item they are posting.  One user wrote his api client to send 28 character guids, and the routing did not give a clear enough error (404 instead of "incorrect guid format")

Answer (score 2):

When I dealt with guid's in my routes, I would accept a string, try to parse the string value to a guid, if it didn't parse, i'd return a different view with a message indicating that the id was invalid and to try again

The only thing you should have to change here would be to remove the route constraint and change your Action to accept a string instead of a guid (unless your action is already accepting a string)

Comment: Yeah it actually already was a string param to the action, and it already did have a check to make sure the string was a valid guid.  But because of the route, it never made it into the action.  I just changed the route to accept any string, and there was no more problem.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to remove the route constraint, then check for a null parameter in your controller and do whatever you want from that point.

Comment: Or add another route immediately after it with everything but the constraint, and go to a different action. That way you can keep the logic separate.

Comment: @bhamlin - good point.  A second route after will catch only if the first one fails.

Comment: There already is a 2nd route with no parameter as shown above: Widgets/guid loads the item, while /Widgets (no param) loads the list

Comment: Yes, JK, but I mean one *with* the param but *without* the constraint. That will only catch if there is an invalid param.